# Changing DialogFragment Layouts while dialog is open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an Android `Activity`, from which I want to show a `Dialog`. It would probably be a custom `DialogFragment`. Now when the user clicks on specific buttons I want the `layout's` inside the `dialog` to change with the data from the previous `DialogFragment` and so that it would have an ability to also go back to previous `Layout`.

I dont think there is an easy way to change views inside of the same `DialogFragment` so what would be the best way to do this?

I have tried doing it in method `onViewCreated` and when a button is clicked, but nothing happens.

In my activity I call the fragment like this at the moment:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    NewDialog newDialog = NewDialog.newInstace(userId, loc, currentId);
    newDialog.setNewClickListener(new NewDialog.OnNewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancelClicked() {
            finishAdd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAcceptClicked() {
            ...
        }
    });
    newDialog.show(fm, "new_frag");
```

And the fragment:

```
public class NewDeliveryPointDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewGroup container;

    public NewDialog(){
    }

    public static NewDialog newInstace(){
        ...
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.container = container;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_1, container);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_layout_2, container);
                view.invalidate();
                view.refreshDrawableState();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create different dialog? For example, when a button is clicked, dismiss current dialog and show another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DialogFragment is not made to have navigation to other fragments within the same dialog.

You basically have these options:

1. On your button click you close the Dialog and open another Dialog. But this seems odd. If there is so much happening, probably dialogs are not the best shot.
2. Instead of DialogFragments have another fragment container overlaying the original one (basically what a Dialog fragment does for you). Within the second container you can easily navigate to other fragments and set it to gone when the user finished interaction.
3. If there are just a few Views in the Dialog, you could consider setting the old ones to `gone` and the new ones to `visible`

Comment: @kataroty did this help or do you need more input?

Comment: Yes it did.. I am really sorry for not granting you the bounty as i was away from internet for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code didn't work, because container is null. Method *onCreateView* gives you *@Nullable ViewGroup container*, which is null for *DialogFragment* (but non null for *Fragment*). So when you call *View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_layout_2, container)*, it just creates a view in memory and doesn't attach it to container, cause it is null. See [LayoutInflater.inflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)), cause [View.inflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) is just a convenience wrapper for this function.

> I dont think there is an easy way to change views inside of the same DialogFragment so what would be the best way to do this?

Instead of changing dialog root you can just manipulate child views inside dialog root layout (add, remove them, or change visibility).

Also my advice is to use [recommended way](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout) to create dialog with custom layout (*onCreateDialog + setView*), but if you don't want to do that, you can refer view you've created in *onCreateView* as dialog root.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a dialog fragment with an empty shell layout in which you would replace your two different fragments with `ChildFragmentManager` and regular fragment transactions

passing data between them can be done using the activity's view model since they  both live in the same activity.

So add the `ShellDialogFragment` using the activity's `FragmentManager` and in the shell fragment class change between `NewDialog` & `NewDeliveryPointDialog` on your button click listener with `ChildFragmentManager`